# DQL to get r_object_id From DRL

Tags: c#, .net, dql, documentum

I have a situation like this. 
I checked out a file from documentum (File is a dita-map ). File has a reference to another file in the repository.
DRL is  dctm://MILLENNIUM/0500006480003b2e?DMS_OBJECT_SPEC=RELATION_ID.
From this, I assume that 0500006480003b2e is the relation ID.  If so how do I get its ObjectID .

I need the object ID of the child in order to checkout that document separately.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your assumptions are correct and assuming my memory is correct

```
select child_id, child_label, permanent_link from dm_relation 
where r_object_id = ID('0500006480003b2e')
```

If permanent_link is TRUE then the child_id is the document's i_chronicle_id and the child_label is used to differentiate the versions.

If permanent_link is FALSE the the child_id is the document's r_object_id.

More details: [Documentum Object Relationships](http://www.ukoom.com/object-relationships-dm_relation.htm)